# iPhone light sensor vs camera to measure the light intensity

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to create an application that measure the light intensity like the ones below:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/luxmeter-pro/id408369821?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/megaman-luxmeter/id455660266?mt=8

and I wonder which is the best way to solve the problem. As I understood it is not possible to use light sensor APIs which are private to Apple. What classes can I use for capture frames and get properties like pixel color or some output that I can convert to Lux later?

Comment: Did you make this app?  I am looking for a good one.

Answer (score 5):

What you really want is to take an image with the camera api and run an algorithm to determine the luminance. You can do this on the fly as well. See below:

Camera Tutorial:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html

Luminance Algorithm:
http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera

Comment: The 'Luminance Algorithm' linked starts interestingly, then ends extremely blunt. Since it doesn't adapt for auto-exposure, it can report equal or higher values whilst the ambient light is lower and vice versa. It should be good at 'dark' vs 'light in most situations, but doesn't offer a consistent metric.