# How to detect intensity of light from iphone camera using iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I want to know that how can we measured intensity of light from iPhone camera, I hope this is possible because now I searched on Appstore and found few apps related to this. Also we know that "Apple does not give developers access to the ambient light sensor on the top of it’s iOS devices". So my question is how can we play with intensity of light from camera? Is there any third party we'll have to use or we can do this from native classes. Any suggestion or helping link would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone light sensor vs camera to measure the light intensity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025764/iphone-light-sensor-vs-camera-to-measure-the-light-intensity) I found this link by putting "iPhone measure light intensity" into Google. You really didn't search that hard did you.

Comment: What are you defining as intensity?